# css insert an image from another website?

Tags: html, css, less

I want to add a background texture image to a web page and to insert the image I used the following rule:

```
background-image: url ('http://s19.postimg.org/r5f8g6uzj/container_pattern.jpg') repeat;
```

the image i want to add is this :http://s19.postimg.org/r5f8g6uzj/container_pattern.jpg;
however its not working and when compiling the less file it gives an error from this rule,
what's wrong or how can it be done?

Comment: remove spaces between url and link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
style="height:300px; width: 200px; background-image: url(http://s19.postimg.org/r5f8g6uzj/container_pattern.jpg); background-repeat: repeat;"
```

1) specify height and width.

2) no space between url and '('

3) no ' wrapped the url

4) single background-repeat property

Answer (score 1):

It works for me 
Your problem is the separation between ->url<- and the ->(' url ');<-

```
<div class="test"> </div>

.test{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: url('http://s19.postimg.org/r5f8g6uzj/container_pattern.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working on my computer, try this

```
 body{
    background: url('http://s19.postimg.org/r5f8g6uzj/container_pattern.jpg');
   }
```

See online Example : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/AWXr8/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be best to save the image to your own server, and then you'll be able to use a local path to the image file.  Some websites may not allow hotlinking to their images.

Comment: maybe he has not server, or it is just a blog

Answer (score 0):

Use like this...
    background-image:url('http://s19.postimg.org/r5f8g6uzj/container_pattern.jpg');